# How to retrieve serialcomm from a query?

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently learning how to create batch scripts, but so far I am doing just queries. I am able to get a list of the current hardware, device map and serial com on the following registry path

```
HKLM\hardware\devicemap\serialcomm
```

The problem is that every computer is displaying a different `serialcomm` on the same device. So I am trying to capture the `serialcomm` based on the device name.

My current code below:

```
reg query HKLM\hardware\devicemap\serialcomm
pause
```

Below is an updated code I have tried to get the `serialcomm` based on the hardware name, but is not working :(

```
set "Comm="
reg query HKLM\hardware\devicemap\serialcomm
if %%hardware%% = ProlificSerial0 set Comm=%%serialcomm%%
pause
```

The above code was created based on all the information I have found on multiple websites, but as I said, I am still learning queries and it is a little bit complicated for me adding more code.

I will appreciate if anybody can tell me what is wrong with the updated code.

Comment: The IF command uses two equal signs.  Not sure why you are using two percent signs for variable expansion.  You never define the hardware variable either so your comparison will never be true.

Comment: you'll need to process the `reg` query with `for` to get the result of the command.

Comment: Squashman I am sorry about that , like I said It is my first time using different functions than query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a batch code with some explaining comments which I wrote a few weeks ago to program Atmel AVR controllers via a batch file using mySmartUSB MK2 being mounted as virtual serial communication port after having once the device driver installed. The code part for programming the fuse bits, flash and eeprom of the AVR controllers is replaced here by a simple information message.

The batch file determines the COM port number

1. from one of several optional command line parameters (special option), or
2. queries it automatically directly from Windows registry (default method), or
3. asks the user of the batch file for the port number (fail safe method).

For the question the identification from Windows registry is the most interesting part.

`DeviceInstance`, `HardwareID` and `ProductName` must be adapted for the Prolific USB-to-Serial converter.

Look with Windows registry editor on registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB
```

for the device instance identifier and hardware identifier (vendor and product identifier) for the Prolific USB-to-Serial converter.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ComPort="
set "DeviceInstance=mySmartUSB2-0001"
set "HardwareID=VID_10C4&PID_EA60"
set "ProductName=mySmartUSB MK2"

cls
echo(
call :ProcessArguments %*
call :CheckPort

echo Serial port of %ProductName% is: COM%ComPort%
echo(
endlocal
pause
exit /B


rem The subroutine ProcessArguments processes the optional parameters of
rem the batch file. For this demo everything except COMx with x being a
rem number in range 1 to 255 is interpreted as unknown parameter.

:ProcessArguments
set "EmptyLine=0"
:NextArgument
if "%~1" == "" (
    if "%EmptyLine%" == "1" echo(
    goto :EOF
)
set "SerialPort=%~1"
if /I "%SerialPort:~0,3%" == "com" (
    set "ComPort=%SerialPort:~3%"
) else (
    echo ERROR: Unknown parameter: %1
    set "EmptyLine=1"
)
shift
goto NextArgument


rem The subroutine CheckPort checks the port number specified as parameter
rem on calling the batch file.

rem In case of no COM port number was specified as parameter, it attempts
rem to determine the COM port number for the device as defined at top of
rem the batch file directly from Windows registry. The registry query is
rem written to work for Windows XP and any later Windows.

rem Last in case of a valid COM port was whether passed to the batch file
rem via COMx parameter nor could the port number be determined from Windows
rem registry automatically, the user is prompted in a loop to enter a valid
rem port number.

:CheckPort
set "EmptyLine=0"
if not "%ComPort%" == "" goto VerifyPort

for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,3" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\%HardwareID%\%DeviceInstance%\Device Parameters" /v PortName 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%A" == "PortName" set "SerialPort=%%B" && goto GetPortNumber
)
goto EnterPort

:GetPortNumber
if /I "%SerialPort:~0,3%" == "com" (
    set "ComPort=%SerialPort:~3%"
    goto VerifyPort
)

:EnterPort
set "EmptyLine=1"
set "ComPort=4"
set /P "ComPort=Enter number of COM port (default: %ComPort%): "

:VerifyPort
for /F "delims=0123456789" %%I in ("%ComPort%") do set "ComPort="
if "%ComPort%" == "" goto EnterPort
if %ComPort% EQU   0 goto EnterPort
if %ComPort% GTR 255 goto EnterPort
if "%EmptyLine%" == "1" echo(
goto :EOF
```

I think, processing `HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM` is not advisable as it lists all serial devices including for example also modems and not only serial ports. Also with hardware identifier known for the device, the COM port number can be found out more quickly directly as demonstrated above.

The `DeviceInstance` identifier often ends with an incrementing number in case of several devices with same vendor and product identifier are connected at the same time on different USB ports.

So for supporting multiple Prolific USB-to-Serial converters connected on same computer it would be better to query first just the hardware identifier to get all device instance identifiers.

Here is a very simple example for ATEN USB to Serial Bridge adapter:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "HardwareID=VID_0557&PID_2008"
set "RegistryPath=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB"
set "ProductName=ATEN USB to Serial Bridge"
set "DeviceFound=0"

cls
echo(
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "%RegistryPath%\%HardwareID%" 2^>nul') do call :GetPort "%%I"

if "%DeviceFound%" == "0" echo WARNING: Could not find any %ProductName%.

echo(
endlocal
pause
exit /B

:GetPort
set "RegistryKey=%~1"
if /I not "%RegistryKey:~0,71%" == "%RegistryPath%\%HardwareID%\" goto :EOF

for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,3" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "%~1\Device Parameters" /v PortName 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%A" == "PortName" set "SerialPort=%%B" && goto OutputPort
)
goto :EOF

:OutputPort
set "DeviceFound=1"
set "DeviceNumber=%RegistryKey:~-1%"
echo %DeviceNumber%. %ProductName% is %SerialPort%.
goto :EOF
```

**Note:** Both batch code examples do not check if each found device is really currently connected to the computer. That would require additional code whereby even cross-checking with values registered currently under `HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM` is not enough as this registry key is not automatically updated when a (virtual) serial COM port device is unplugged. It is only always updated when a serial COM port device is plugged in.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `shift /?`

Comment: Hi Mofi , I have copied the ATEN USB batch code but when I apply that example using my information I am getting all the ports where my USB adapter was connected . I would like to know just on which PORT is currently connected

Answer (score 0):

I have no serialcomm on my machine but you can use this as reference:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=3* delims= " %%a in (
    'reg query HKLM\hardware\devicemap\pointerclass'
) do (
    set "pointer=%%a"

)

echo %pointer%
if "%pointer%" equ "REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\mouclass" echo need to set something
```

Comment: My only question is where do I type the device name ProlificSerial0 ?

Comment: @Sam - the only place using this in your code is in IF condition.Though I have no idea where the `hardware` variable comes from. And do you want to set something in the registry? You'll need another `reg` expression in such case.

Comment: My computer is showing a list of hardware names with the COM port for each of them but I need to capture the Com port from one of those device with an specific hardware name and then use the int value as a variable

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the specific value you are looking for as an argument to your batch file. For instance, if your batch file is named **RegSearch**, the command line syntax should be Something like:

```
RegSearch ProlificSerial0
```

You should therefore do a little bit of syntax checking inside the batch file to make sure you aren't forgetting to specify the argument when you run the batch file.
In addition, you can add the **/v** parameter to the **Reg Query** command in order to look for a specific value (rather than looking through all the keys). You can then filter the query results with **findstr** to determine if it was successful.

The following code should do all of that:

```
@echo off  
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if /i "%1"=="" goto syntax
set myValue=%1
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ('reg query hklm\hardware\devicemap\serialcomm /v *%myValue%* ^| findstr /i %myValue%') do (
  set comm=%%a
  echo !comm!
)

goto :eof

:syntax
echo.
echo ERROR : invalid syntax. You must pass the value to look for as the first argument, for example:
echo RegSearch Prolificserial0
```

Comment: I have reviewed all the codes but your code is short and I have tested it as well but I am getting the error message . I just copied it without modifying anything but I assume that I have to replace something on the code right ? .  I am sorry I'm not good using batch scripts :(

Comment: As I explained in my answer: copy the code and save it as **Regsearch.bat**. Then, to use it, type **RegSearch ProlificSerial0** to assign the value of _ProlificSerial0_ to the _comm_ variable.